# Communicating Between Blazor app and Microservice api using azure service bus

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microservices, blazor-server-side, azure-servicebus-queues

I am creating a microservice where one app is sending selected filters to other app using azure service bus queue.

I am able to send and receive the message however unable to use received message in my SQL Query.

The API is getting hit by one application (frontend).

.../api/User

Our controller

```
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
      public IEnumerable<dynamic> Get()
        {
           
            return userRepository.GetAll();
        }
}
```

GetAll method

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetAll()
        {
           
             ReceiveMsg().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // We have called receiveMsg from here
            
                startdate = content1[0];
                enddate = content1[1];

                using (IDbConnection dbConnection = connection)
                {
var result = connection.Query("select * from [User] where DateofBirth between '" + startdate + "' and'" + enddate + "'");
                    
                    return result;
                }
      
        }
```

Receive Message method`

```
public static async Task ReceiveMsg()
        {
         // 
            string sbConnectionString = <connection string for Service Bus namespace>;
            string sbQueueName = <Queue name>;
        try
        {
            queueClient = new QueueClient(sbConnectionString, sbQueueName);

            var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
            {
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
                AutoComplete = false
            };
             queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ReceiveMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
            await queueClient.CloseAsync();
        }
    }



 public static async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Received message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");
    var receivedmsg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
    
    ServiceBusMessage DeserializeMsg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceBusMessage>(receivedmsg);
     
    content1 = DeserializeMsg.Content;

    await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
}



static Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two paradigms here - a message pump and receive messages on demand. With a message pump, when using `.ReceiveMessageHandler()` you're requesting the Service Bus SDK to run a continuous loop, aka "message pump", to receive messages as they arrive. That doesn't align with an explicit message retrieval when making a request to the Web API (via controller). You need to redesign your application and retrieve the message(s) upon demand rather than running a message pump.

Comment: Can you please suggest any diffent approach

Comment: "You need to redesign your application and retrieve the message(s) upon demand rather than running a message pump." Specifically, use `MessageReceiver` to retrieve one (or more) messages on demand when the controller is invoked. And even that is not great. You should review what are you trying to achieve and design accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion